# Как убрать уведомление "Опасный сайт"?

Tags: google-chrome, безопасность, firefox, браузер, opera

Зарегистрировали новый домен и хостинг. Сайт в продакшен еще не выгружали, но при переходе по ссылке/домену, показывает уведомление: "Опасный сайт, Если вы посетите этот сайт, злоумышленники могут обманом заставить вас установить ПО...". Показывает такое на всех браузерах: хром, опера, мозилла.

При том, что сайта еще нет, но пишет "что сайт, который вы хотите посетить, является фишинговым". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решать эту проблему??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Меняй домен, если хочешь надёжно и быстро. Иначе - вести переговоры с производителями этой таблички. Ну т.е. с производителями браузеров.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, производитель этой таблички - Google, так как он завязал на себя практически весь DNS, и ваш сайт попал в чёрный список. Обелить очень тяжело. Эта тема широко обсуждается в Интернете, погуглите.

Answer (score -1):

Возможные варианты почему браузеры показывают это сообщение:

1. Отсутствие SSL соединения(https). Также отсутствие сертификата домена.
2. Невалидный, просроченный или неправильный сертификат домена.
3. DNS домена настроен не правильно и ведет на другой сервер, что ведет к пункту 2.

Если у вас действительно новый домен, ранее он нигде не регистрировался, то вам нужно первично настроить DNS зону, выпустить сертификат и настроить хостинг чтобы сайт и хостинг работал используя ваш сертификат домена. Если же вы не настраивали хостинг и не выгружали сайт в "продакшен" то и не понятно какой сайт должен обслуживаться по этому домену.
Советую выгрузить сайт на хостинг, подключить его к домену и добавить SSL/TLS сертификат вашего домена для правильной работы защищенного соединения, после уже решать проблемы по мере поступления.

Comment: Ни в одном из этих случаев браузеры не называют сайт сайтом злоумышленников